# How to compare & replace x10 variable with a String containing x10 inside

Tags: java, regex, string, variables, replace

I've been trying to do:

```
double x10 = 2.4;  
String str = "The value of a variable is x10";  
int c = 0;  
while(c<str.length) #Here digit means a valid Number  
if(str.charAt[c]==digit && str.charAt[c+1]==digit){  
  str.charAt[c] = Double.toString(x10);
}
```

Desired Output:

```
The value of a variable is 2.4
```

Problem:

```
The problem is that it doesn't seems to be comparing 10 in a String,  
so that it can replace the x10 in the string with the value of variable x10.
```

Is there any other way to achieve the desired goal???

```
it works fine with variable x(1-9) but when it exceeds x10 & greater it stucks.  
Didn't found anything relevant to my problem.
```

Any help would be highly encouraged!

Comment: Try [`str.replaceAll("x\d+", x10)`](https://regex101.com/r/uxnmXu/1)

Comment: @S.Jovan, I need to check all the variable before replacing it. My string contains x10 - x30 inside it, where after matching with every x10-x30 it will then be replaced by its corresponding value which is in double[] x10-x30. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does `double[]` x10-x30 mean in code?

Comment: @NetMage ... For Example:  String str = "sig ( x12 + 2.42 * x23 - x8 )"; then I've double [] x12, x23, x8 & so on where every double[] contains multiple values. I just want to replace x12, x23 & x8 of the string with the values in x12[i], where i ranges from (0-n) . So, the loop will be used to replace and calculate the string in mathematical form. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you updated your question with what you really meant to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are in C#. You can use the `Regex.Replace` variant that takes a `MatchEvaluator` delegate. Assuming your values are in `double[] values` and that they substitutions are one off in value (e.g. "x1" corresponds to `values[0]`), you do:

```
var ans = Regex.Replace(str, @"x(\d+)", m => values[Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value)-1].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

After so many tries, in order to achieve the desired output. I finally figured it out the way to solve it.

```
    String str = "x12",str2 = "x1";
    if(str2.matches("x[0-9]{1}")==true){

        int var = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1,2));
        System.out.println(var);

    }else{
        System.out.println("Not Found!");

    }if(str.matches("x[0-9]{2}")==true){

        int var = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1,2));
        int var2 = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2,3));
        var = var * 10 + var2;
        System.out.println(var);

    }else{
        System.out.println("Not Found!");
    }
```

Comment: The Task was not to make it work with x1-x9 but with x10-x99 variables, so let me add that condition for you.